# Special Chars like Â not escaping from JSTL while triggering Email

Tags: jsp, jstl, websphere-commerce, jstl-functions

I know this might have asked 1000 times, but I dont see a proper answer to this issue. I am trying to email a list of products in my IBM wbsphere commerce application. 
I am not able to escape the product names with speical chars through jstl. for eg:
in the application the product name shows as "Product®" but when I email the product name it shows " ProductÂ® ".
I tried following ways but no luck in JSTL

```
<c:out value="${name}" escapeXml="true"/>
<c:out value="${name}" escapeXml="false"/>
${fn:escapeXml(name)}
```

and adding following config in web.xml. Any help is much appreciated

```
<jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
</jsp-property-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to encode as HTML, there are libraries for this from apache and others.